# What is systemProperties in Spring and where to find it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-el, system-properties

I'm reading `Spring In Action` book and there's is an example:

```
public BlankDisc(@Value("#{systemProperties['disc.title']}" String title){
}
```

But what is `systemProperties` here and where to declare it? I thought it was `application.properties` file and added `disc.title=Beatles` there. But the value of `title` variable is `null` when the bean is created. I can inject the value of `disc.title` if i use `@Value("${disc.title}")` by the way.

Comment: SystemProperties here are the normal system properties defined while starting any java process, using -D flag. What you are seeing is just spring shorthand for referencing it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the property that will be set while starting the jar like "java -Dproperty.name="value" -jar app.jar"

Comment: Is it possible to refer properties defined in application properties in SPEL?

Answer (score 6):

For example if you run application `java -jar app.jar -Dmy.param=myParam`

then you can create bean

```
@Bean
public String myParam(){
   return System.getProperty("my.param");
}
```

and inject by `@Autowiere`